# Trouble saving data like 12 ÷ 5

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have following data to save in database using php

my data is : `12 ÷ 5`

I have the following code:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "add_proc.php",
    data: "topic="+ encodeURIComponent(field1)
```

When I check value of field1 in firebug it's the same `12 ÷ 5`, but when value is saved in database it's `12 Ã· 5`.

```
     $topic=mysql_escape_string($_POST['topic']);
      echo($topic);
```

Even if I echo the value of variable after post, I get `12 Ã· 5`.

I can't figure out where the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `÷` is being UTF-8 encoded -- http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00f7/

```
#pseudo
utf8('÷')    => 'Ã' + '·'
utf8(0x00F7) => 0xC3, 0xB7
```

You can use [`utf8_decode`](http://php.net/utf8_decode) (I'm guessing the encoding is from `$_POST`):

```
$topic = mysql_escape_string(utf8_decode($_POST['topic']));
```

Be sure that your database/tables have [Unicode/UTF-8 support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode.html).

Alternatively, leave it encoded and just `echo` as is with UTF-8 encoding in the page (as Ates Goral suggested) so the browser will handle the decoding for you.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Comment: I don't know if I'd recommend `utf8_decode()`.  That doesn't really address the problem, but rather skirts around it by changing the encoding to ISO-8859-1, which then means you're basically ditching UTF-8 support.

Answer (score 1):

This is *definitely* an encoding problem.  Here's why.

The division sign ([U+00F7](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00f7/index.htm)) is encoded in UTF-8 as 2 bytes, 0xC3 and 0xB7.

But in [ISO-8859-1](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/ISO-8859-1/list.htm) (and many other encodings) those bytes individually are two separate characters: [U+00C3](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00c3/index.htm) and [U+00B7](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00b7/index.htm) respectively.

So *somewhere* in the process your UTF-8 encoded division sign is being decoded as some other encoding (ISO-8859-1 most likely).

Check out the [PHP UTF-8 Cheatsheet](http://developer.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet) as a start.  If you work through all those steps and still have a problem, let me know and I'll see what I can do to help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the content encoding of your input HTML page is UTF-8. That way, PHP will know that the content that it is receiving is in UTF-8.

You can do this by embedding the following in the head of your document:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

**Update:** Also make sure that the HTML that you're generating (echo'ing from) also reports UTF-8 as the content encoding. Once you get the echo working, the next step is to ensure that you're DB is also expecting/storing UTF-8.

Comment: You'll also want to make sure the database table is using UTF8 encoding as well.

Comment: Note that this won't work if the server is already specifying a different character encoding in an HTTP header; the header takes precedence, as per the HTML 4.01 spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/charset.html#h-5.2.2. More on this from the WHAT-WG: http://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-character-encoding

Comment: my php page add_proc.php has

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

but after echo i can see same result.